# Purpose and origin of temporary .o files generated by GHC

Tags: haskell, compilation, linker, ghc

As a part of developing my understanding of GHC, I would like to be able manually link GHC generated assembly against the GHC rts  (and other necessary libraries) to produce a runnable file.
Specifically...
I have a file `helloworld.hs` whose contents are simply

```
main = putStrLn "Hello, World! again"
```

If I run `ghc -c -o helloworld.o  helloworld.hs` to generate assembly.
I would like to know how to manually link `helloworld.o`
If I run `ghc -o runnable helloworld.o -v3` to see how ghc accomplishes this (with verbose output) I see this.

```
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.10.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.10.3
Using binary package database: /usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/package.cache
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.4.0.0-6cdc86811872333585fa98756aa7c51e
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-1.0.0.0-3c8c40657a9870f5c33be17496806d8d
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.8.2.0-0d6d1084fbc041e1cded9228e80e264d
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.10.0.0-3c4cb52230f347282af9b2817f013181
wired-in package ghc mapped to ghc-7.10.3-624693c6aa854116c707bc7b4d0d7cb6
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags: 
Created temporary directory: /tmp/ghc54ce_0
*** C Compiler:
/usr/bin/gcc -fno-stack-protector -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -c /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_1.c -o /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_2.o -I/usr/lib/ghc/include
*** C Compiler:
/usr/bin/gcc -fno-stack-protector -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -c /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_4.s -o /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_5.o -I/usr/lib/ghc/include
*** Linker:
/usr/bin/gcc -fno-stack-protector -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE '-Wl,--hash-size=31' -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads -Wl,--no-as-needed -o final helloworld.o -L/usr/lib/ghc/base_HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM -L/usr/lib/ghc/integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS -L/usr/lib/ghc/ghcpr_8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3 -L/usr/lib/ghc/rts /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_2.o /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_5.o -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_static_info -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_static_info -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_static_info -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_static_info -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Wzh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziInt_I8zh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziInt_I16zh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziInt_I32zh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziInt_I64zh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziWord_W8zh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziWord_W16zh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziWord_W32zh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziWord_W64zh_static_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_static_info -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_con_info -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_con_info -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_con_info -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_con_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_con_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziPtr_FunPtr_con_info -Wl,-u,base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_con_info -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_False_closure -Wl,-u,ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_True_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziPack_unpackCString_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziIOziException_stackOverflow_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziIOziException_heapOverflow_closure -Wl,-u,base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nonTermination_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnMVar_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnSTM_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziIOziException_allocationLimitExceeded_closure -Wl,-u,base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nestedAtomically_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziEventziThread_blockedOnBadFD_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziWeak_runFinalizzerBatch_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziTopHandler_flushStdHandles_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziTopHandler_runIO_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziTopHandler_runNonIO_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziConcziIO_ensureIOManagerIsRunning_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziConcziIO_ioManagerCapabilitiesChanged_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziConcziSync_runSparks_closure -Wl,-u,base_GHCziConcziSignal_runHandlersPtr_closure -lHSbase-4.8.2.0-HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM -lHSinteger-gmp-1.0.0.0-2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS -lHSghc-prim-0.4.0.0-8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3 -lHSrts -lgmp -lm -lrt -ldl -lffi
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_7.rsp /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_6.rsp /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_5.o /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_4.s /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_3.rsp /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_2.o /tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_1.c
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc54ce_0
```

I cannot simply use a similar call to gcc to link helloworld.o myself. If you look at the output above, gcc actually creates `/tmp/ghc54ce_0` which ends up holding seven different temporary files. Two of these files are object files that the code is linked against.
I'm having a hard time finding where the initial `/tmp/ghc54ce_0/ghc_1.c` is coming from. I'm also curious why this part of the process is necessary (i.e. what is being generated that could not be contained in a static library that isn't already in helloworld.o).
Any direct information, or good leads on where to find answers would be appreciated!

Comment: [This](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#id532516) may be the flag you're looking for.

Comment: That is useful, but not what I'm looking for. The files still get autodeleted when using the tmpdir flag. The main thing I'm looking for is more insight to the origin of the ghc_1.c file (of course, evaluation of its contents might yield some clues. I'll try and disallow file deletion within the tmpdir sometime soon here)

Comment: Have you tried ignoring them?  I'm linking a project manually (albeit embedded -- so I wrote my own main in C++) and it's working fine, I haven't had to worry about this tmp stuff.

Comment: @Culex I think you are looking at the wrong flag - you probably want `-keep-tmp-files`, which, as the flag name would imply, will cause GHC to not delete temporary files. You can redirect them as well, but that is a seperate concern.

Comment: Thanks so much for the helpful input! I can manage linking manually, and I will be using the `-keep-tmp-files` flag to examine file contents eventually here. I am still curious about the nature of the files though. I'll edit the question to clarify that.